# Why is this markdown code block not rendering properly?

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting

I've been trying to edit [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610062/424509) to get the two code blocks in the middle formatted as code, but for the life of me I can't. In the preview the first one gets half-formatted, but it's not converted properly into a code block in the final post. I tried it [in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116924/151110) as well, but no dice.

And just for reference, here's the code block:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'P5' => {
    'E' => '06' => [100, 200, 95]
    'B' => '23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]
  },
  'P2' => {
    'C' => '24' => [18, 23, 2300, 3456]
  },
  'P1' => {
    'A' => '12' => [24, 25, 3200, 5668]
    'D' => '15' => [168]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code blocks had some whitespace problems. The lines weren't indented by spaces alone. Not sure what the characters between the spaces were, but they were throwing Markdown parser off.

NullUserException beat me to the edit, but it's all fixed up now either way.

Comment: The characters where non-breaking spaces (U+00A0).