# Problem with numbered lists

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

In [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216151/updating-google-maps-marker-from-a-broadcast-sms-receiver/10216546#10216546), I wrote up a solution with step-by-step instructions. However, my numbered items are being reset to 1. This only happens in *Item B* and *Item C*. The first section of my answer doesn't suffer from this problem.

Is this a bug in markdown, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/52738)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's tricky to mix code blocks and numbered lists. You need to indent the code blocks 8 spaces (4 to put them "inside" the numbered list and 4 to make them code blocks):

This markup:

```
1. foo bar:

        some.code()

2. baz quux
```

produces this result:

1. foo bar:

   ```
   some.code()
   ```
2. baz quux

Comment: "You need to indent the code blocks 8 spaces (4 to put them "inside" the numbered list and 4 to make them code blocks)"  Thanks, I never new that, it's something I struggled with on a few answers. +1

Answer (score 3):

I have edited your post you can see what I've done.

In addition to what Joachim said, you also had some fancy space character in some of your lines, for example:

map.getOverlays().add(overlay);

As you can see although it's indented it's not recognized as code block because those are not ordinary space character (ASCII value 32) but something else. I verified it in [this online tool](http://easycalculation.com/ascii-hex.php) which says those characters are NULL.

Replacing it with ordinary spaces:

```
               map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
```

Solved the issue of course. What IDE are you using? Maybe something there went funky.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Eclipse and instructed it to convert tabs into spaces, but this may not be happening correctly...

Comment: @Tony any chance you're under Korean, Chinese, or Japanese language settings on your machine? I believe it cause such a "double space" character.

Comment: No, just a basic US English install. What's a good tool to sanitize whitespace and tabs prior to posting?

Comment: @Tony that's really weird then. Not aware of any such tool, but if you see your code won't get formatted even with spaces it probably means fake spaces.

Comment: @Tony: [Other users have had the same problem with spaces-that-are-not-spaces when using Chrome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125587/indenting-markdown-with-non-regular-unicode-spaces-does-not-create-a-correct-cod).