# Code markdown quirk?

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do code blocks sometimes not “show” properly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly)

Code markdown seems to break down for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032719/50552):

[image]

The markdown itself looks OK:

[image]

Did something change recently in the markdown display mechanism?

Comment: You somehow introduced non-breaking spaces into the last three lines. Can you add your browser information, as well as how you got the code into the editor (copied from an IDE vs. typed directly, etc)?

Comment: @TimStone: Google Chrome on Win8, pretty sure I typed this directly in the browser.  Is there a shortcut key for a non-breaking space?

Comment: I'm not sure about a shortcut, but I do know that this (random non-breaking spaces appearing) has happened to other people in Chrome before. Unfortunately, reproducing it hasn't proven to be very easy.

Comment: Using Eclipse by any chance? See [this related answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129721/152859) I posted a while ago.

Comment: @TimStone: Looks like `alt-space` is a shortcut for nonbreakable space in Chrome, at least under MacOS X

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what wonderful characters were used instead of a space on those three lines, but re-indenting the lines fixed the issue.

When deleting the whitespace characters one-by-one, the preview display showed that every second 'space' did not affect the display; perhaps it was a non-breaking space instead of a regular space.

In other words, not a markdown bug, but rather a case of unsupported input.

Comment: Well found, "bug" seemed the most fitting of the meta required tags +1