# What's happening to StackOverflow's code formatter?

Tags: bug

I answered this question on StackOverflow:

[How to calculate time taken to load url in UIWebView in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699386/detect-time-taken-to-load-url-in-uiwebview-in-iphone/11699409#11699409)

It has been now edited, but the problem with the original revison is, the code in the second line is not actually marked as code, it seems the markup engine fails to correctly interpret the indentation. I have indented that line with at least 4 (actually 8) spaces. The same weird thing happened to me earlier this day also.

What's going on with SO? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There was probably a tab in there or a special character (an invisible one) most likely copied in from the original paste operation. The edit removed it it seems.

Comment: See [Why do code blocks sometimes not “show” properly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly)

Comment: @jmort253 thanks - but I haven't pasted in anything... Nevermind. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why accept anything that doesn't solve things for you?

Comment: And did you see [balpha's request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly/125863#125863) in the post I linked to? He asks *"please see if the text area has a changed `white-space` setting"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs or a special character (an invisible one) most likely copied in from the original paste operation, can have an effect on the way the editor interprets the markup. The edit removed it it seems.

I investigated the first revision and edited it myself. Removing the 4 blank characters and replacing them with normal spaces resolves the problem.

In this case, editing the post to fix the code formatting is indeed the correct course of action. In short, you're not doing anything wrong, just make sure it's 4 actual spaces (ASCII code 32 type spaces) and all will work just fine.

For more specifics, an [online ASCII converter](http://www.easycalculation.com/ascii-hex.php) detected 4 regular spaces before the actual line of code, but it also detected a NULL value. I also confirmed through trial and error that the very first space, when deleted and re-entered, fixed the formatting; thus, it may not be necessary to replace all 4 spaces in these situations.

Line entered from the actual first revision:

> NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url

Output from ASCII converter:

```
NULL 32 32 32 32
```

Comment: The first char is actually `0xA0` ie `NBSP`.

Comment: I read that in the linked post. Maybe it's because I converted to the actual numerical ASCII codes instead of HTML. At any rate, there are other characters that could affect the markup as well. I've cleaned up plenty of poorly formatted questions that had tabs instead of spaces. Now that's a real nightmare to clean up.

Comment: `0xA0` is outside of 7-bit ASCII which is what that converter is using. It's NBSP in Latin1 and other ISO-8859 charsets.

Comment: *I've cleaned up plenty of poorly formatted questions that had tabs instead of spaces* — But Tabs should be okay, [and the preview should match the actual rendering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/how-does-the-editor-handle-tab-characters/83420#83420)? Of course, if people are only peeking into the editor textarea, then things might look horrible. (Kudos for fixing that then.)