# No last activity link when the only answers are deleted

Tags: bug, status-deferred, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

On questions that have answers, links that say "modified x mins ago" point to

- `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/####/slug/?lastactivity`

On questions where there are no (undeleted) answers, the link is to

- `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/####/slug`

If you're a 10k+ user and the most recent activity is on a deleted answer, the first link will send you to that deleted answer, which is expected ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/whats-happening-to-stackoverflows-code-formatter/?lastactivity)). The second link just sends you to the question ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320850/don-t-rate-limit-archive-org-as-much)). In addition, questions with only deleted answers don't have "active today" in the upper right sidebar, which would serve as a link to the most recent activity.

This behavior is confusing, especially when there are several deleted answers.

I first noticed this on the [active homepage on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active), but it also occurs pretty often on the [voted unanswered page on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) because many questions there have several deleted answers.

Comment: We’ve reviewed this request and have moved it to our backlog. I’ve updated the status to [status-deferred].

Comment: @Slate does it mean all 208 questions here with the deferred tag are in the official backlog? If not, any chance for a cleanup and leaving only those in the backlog?

Comment: @Shadow As it stands right now, past a certain date, everything [status-review] gets added to our backlog, and everything [status-deferred] past that date should be in there as well. Tackling historical posts has become a pretty large project internally -- my understanding is that we'd like to tackle historical [status-deferred] posts eventually. We'd ideally like [status-review] and [status-deferred] to accurately reflect where posts are in process.