# Why is my code format not working?

Tags: support, markdown

I've been seeing this problem a lot lately.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345305/invert-an-image-based-on-color-under-it/14345888#14345888), I am unable to get the second code block to indent. However, the markdown is identical to the first - what is wrong?

#### EDIT:

Pasting the content into this post causes the same issue:

Red:   #ff0000
    Black: #000000

```
Result == Red `xnor` Black
       == Red ^ ~Black
       == #ff0000 ^ #ffffff
       == #00ffff
       == Cyan
```

View [the source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/37dd8ce4-870b-43ad-9ec8-d74d13a0853a/view-source) and you'll see everything looks OK.

Comment: Related: [Why do code blocks sometimes not “show” properly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly) (Please see Balpha's answer there, and comment on that?)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some no break spaces (`&#160;`) there. When I delete them and reinsert regular spaces:

```
Red:   #ff0000
Black: #000000

Result == Red `xnor` Black
       == Red ^ ~Black
       == #ff0000 ^ #ffffff
       == #00ffff
       == Cyan
```

Whatever editor you are using is inserting no break spaces that confuse the parser.

I am seeing characters #160 (no break space) and #32 (space) instead of just regular spaces.

Comment: I'm typing things straight into my browser here

Comment: @Eric - Using what? Whatever it is adds a character #160 to the space.

Comment: A combination of copy and paste from other parts of my answer and the markdown buttons to indent things for me. Perhaps it's a chrome extension screwing with me. More investigation by me required, I guess