# Why is this last line of C++ code not formatted as code?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

In [Mark Wilkins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123108/78845) to [Counter not giving the expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15123068/78845), he has some [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code that looks like this:

```
   if (i == var4)
   {
        cout << "\n Armstrong number " << counter << ": " << var4;
        counter++;
   }
```

i++;

`i++` is not formatted as code, despite having the same indentation as the line directly above it (which is).

[image: Screenshot for effect]

Why is this so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The spaces *looked* identical but were not.  It must be indented with **plain spaces**, no crazy unicode or tabs.

Comment: Nice spot, thanks! `20c2 a020 c2a0 20c2 a020 692b 2b3b 0a     .. .. .. i++;.`

Comment: Funny thing is, using Chrome on Mac, **sometimes** my spacebar will insert a no-breaking space too... Perhaps I accidentally hit a modifier key somewhere.

Comment: It happens to me too, but I don't recall hitting any modifier.

Comment: Tabs actually work just fine.

Comment: This happened to me once too -- and it was also with Chrome on the Mac.

Comment: Nick, note that [someone else reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169766/code-not-formatted-as-code#comment501607_169766) *"in Chrome on Windows 7 Pro, I copied a block of code already in the site and pasted it just below the block that I copied - doubling the size of the block"*. @Ernest, do you happen to remember if it was a copy & paste action for you too? And please see balpha's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly/125863#125863) if it ever happens again...

Comment: @Arjan -- I believe it was indeed copy/paste, not from within the site, but from some other app into Chrome.