# Why is this line in my question not getting formatted correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Can someone let me know why the "var date5 . ." line [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170391/in-c-how-can-i-parse-out-monthly-items-from-a-collection-of-datetime-objects/15174419#15174419) is not getting formatted as code in the question markdown (like the 4 lines above it) as it seems to be identical indentation, etc ?

Is this a bug in the markdown parser?

Comment: Any details on the browser/OS you were using, and where you copied/pasted from?

Comment: And please see balpha's answer there, and comment if you have useful details. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had two no break spaces `&#160;` instead of normal spaces - `&#32;`.

Replacing them solved the formatting issue.

Comment: "let's fix that....great....do a writeup....damn Oded!!" ;)

Comment: No comment, @Bart

Comment: Hmmm, that's [twice today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169766/code-not-formatted-as-code). See also [Why do code blocks sometimes not “show” properly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125658/why-do-code-blocks-sometimes-not-show-properly)

Comment: Yep. This comes up every now and then. People copying and pasting code from browsers, often time.